# ObserveOnDispatcher not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, system.reactive

I have 2 threads, WPF+PIPE. I register the from the WPF on the pipe rx event.
when using ObserveOnDispatcher() the registered handler is not called, when removing the ObserveOnDispatcher() it is called on the pipe thread.
Does anyone have ideas why it is not called at all when using ObserveOnDispatcher()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DispatcherObservable.ObserveOnDispatcher` takes the dispatcher of the *current thread* at the time when it is called. If you call it from a background thread, it will look for a dispatcher on that thread (if it has one).

If you want to call back to the UI thread, you'll need to get the `IScheduler` from `Scheduler.Dispatcher` *while on the UI thread* (like at the start of the application) and pass that instance to your background thread. You can then use `ObserveOn(dispatcherSchedulerInstance)` to schedule back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code? :)

In general i'd look for any place where you might be blocking the ui thread, since the wpf dispatcher is single threaded, a blocking operation on the dispatcher will cause your subscribe callback to never be executed.

Comment: I have just found that when I call the ObserveOnDispatcher().subscribe() from the pipe thread it doesn't but when I call it from the WPF thread it works!

Comment: ObserveOnDispatcher uses the 'current' dispatcher, so for a regular thread, that will be the ThreadPool. From a wpf thread it will be the using the wpf dispatcher associated with that thread. im not sure i understand if your problem was solved or not though :)

Comment: it was solved because I moved the subscribe to the WPF thread. But I have assumed the ObserveOnDispatcher method will register on application WPF dispatcher where ever it is called.

Comment: all right :) after looking a bit closer it seems like ObserveOnDispatcher creates a new wpf dispatcher if one does not exsist for the current thread, in other words it does **not** use the thread pool. This could be a problem if the new dispatcher isnt pumped (by wpf or manually). This means ObserveOnDispatcher shoule be called from a UI thread, not from a custom thread, unless there is some special reason for it

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `ObserveOnDispatcher()` using the current dispatcher rather than the "main" UI dispatcher, I ran into this even when using `ObserveOn()` with a specific, previously-captured dispatcher scheduler.

The issue turned out to be that using some observable methods, in particular the `Buffer()` overloads with a time period, disconnects the observable from its previous `ObserveOn` context and cause it to be observed from a separate "timer" task.  As a result, the `ObserveOn` must be done after the call to `Buffer()`.