# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The current thread has no Dispatcher associated with it.'

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database

//I get that Error  while fetching data from Firebase Database to DataGridView.

// This is the code for Fetching the data

```
 var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://megaapp-app.firebaseio.com/");

            var observable = firebase.Child("Orders")

                .AsObservable<OrderDetails>();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = observable.ObserveOnDispatcher()

                .AsObservableCollection();
```

// This is the Code for my OrderDetails Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EMega_Standard_Online_Management_System
{
    class OrderDetails
    {

        public string CustomerLocation { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerPhone { get; set; }
        public string OrderDate { get; set; }
        public string OrderedProducts { get; set; }
        public string OrderTotalPrice { get; set;}
        public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Thank You For Your Time

Comment: Hello!  Have you searched StackOverflow for similar questions and answers?  How about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6043488/3791245f)?  Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25187995/3791245)?  A common theme from these and other answers is to avoid using `ObserveOnDispatcher`, which will just grab the current dispatcher for the thread you are running on, and instead use `ObserveOn`, passing in the specific dispatcher you want to use.

Comment: Thank you , But i have tried it and still i have no luck , has anyone had success about making a DataGridView in windows forms Application fetch real time info from firebase database.